# How to trigger save on Wordpress media modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, save, advanced-custom-fields

I made a custom field by using ACF plugin. This value should be stored inside DB. Also, this field is hidden from the user.

To manipulate the data from ACF field I use JS - I added another field which is visible to the user. Once the user makes the input in visible field the input is processed and sent to the hidden field.

I managed to do the previously said, but the problem is that the data is not saved to the database when I edit the visible input field, even though the value of the hidden field is changed.

When I edit the value of the hidden field directly, the data is stored.

Is there a way to trigger save inside WP media modal?

I was looking at the `wp.media`, but don't understand this quite well. I assume there might be something.

I need something like.

```
$('.hidden-field').on('change', function(){
    saveValue();
})
```